# Changing the legend labels in a windrose from R openair

Tags: r, legend

I made a graph using `windRose` from the `openair` package. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(openair)
windRose(mydata, ws="ws", wd="wd", breaks=c(0,1.5,3.3,5.4,7.9,10.7), 
             auto.text= FALSE, paddle = FALSE, annotate = FALSE)
```

I found that I can change the legend title, footer and position by `key.header`, `key.footer` and `key.position`. But I would like to change the legend labels, so the "1.5 to 3.3", to be used in another language than English ("1.5 zu 3.3") or for example to "2 Beaufort". Is there an easy way?

Comment: In `windRose` function, you can add argument `key = list(labels = c())`. You can define your own labels.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks! That was what i was looking for. If you add it as an answer all accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `windRose` function, you can add argument `key = list(labels = c())`. You can define your own labels, such as:

```
library(openair)
windRose(mydata, ws="ws", wd="wd", breaks=c(0,1.5,3.3,5.4,7.9,10.7), 
         auto.text= FALSE, paddle = FALSE, annotate = FALSE,
         key = list(labels = c("0 zu 1.5", "1.5 zu 3.3", "3.3 zu 5.4", 
                               "5.4 zu 7.9", "7.9 zu 10.7", 
                               "10.7 zu 20.16")))
```

[image]